# Bring program started in bat file to the foreground

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I've created a bat file containing the following line:

```
start "" "C:\My Programs\NotepadPlus\notepad++.exe" %1
```

I've converted that file to "Open with NPP.EXE" and set it as the default program for some file types.

---

If I select multiple file in File Explorer and press "Open", Notepad++ opens those files but remains in the background and its tab in the Taskbar is flashing.

How can I change that and bring Notepad++ to the foreground?

Comment: I tested your .BAT file code and cannot recreate your problem.  Every file I drag and drop onto the batch file brings NP++ into focus.

Comment: _But surely @Squashman, their code uses `%1` and when you `select multiple CSS file in File Explorer and press "Open"` only the first one did! And even had they used `%*` all of them didn't come into focus at the same time did they?_

Comment: @Squashman, Thanks for replying. I have no problem with Drag & Drop. The problem is when I select multiple files, right-click and "Open".

Comment: It is very easy to configure Windows to open files of different types (file extensions) like `.log`, `.txt`, `.text`, `.tsv`, `.xml` all with an application like Notepad++ and use for each file type a different icon. There is really no need for what you try to achieve with a batch file packed (converted) completely useless into an executable.

Comment: @Yaron so we have proven that the batch file works which means that the issue has something to do with the Operating System.

Comment: Squashman, Thanks again. @Mofi, It's indeed easy on Windows 7. I haven't been able to do that on Windows 10 (tried Default Programs Editor and others). Can you enlighten me? Thanks.

Comment: @Mofi, Thank you. https://superuser.com/questions/1644129/windows-10-assign-a-unique-icon-to-file-types-associated-with-the-same-program